# Would I not notice proper space in the same way that I don't notice proper time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, causality

I'm working to understand the metric tensor in spacetime (including 4 dimension lengths and 6 angles).  I know that if I'm carrying a clock near a black hole I won't notice that my proper time is any different from if I'm anywhere else in space.  In the same vein, if I'm carrying a cube box will I not notice that my warped space is any different because I am experiencing the same warping as the box?  Near a black hole do I even notice the spaghettification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaghettification occurs due to a difference between the gravitational pull on your feet and on your head (in other words, it is due to tidal forces). Hence, you will feel you are being stretched, and eventually undergo a painful death.

If the tidal effects are negligible (in other words, if you are looking only at a sufficiently small scale), then you won't notice anything weird about space. For example, we can't notice Lorentz contraction. Our perception of time is always an instant at a time, and hence we can't really notice any strange effects "just by existing". However, if we consider extended time scales, we can notice some differences, as happens in the twin paradox.